# Why EventEmitter not working (firing) on mat-menu?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have angular/material project.
I have problem with custom directive @Output() `EventEmiter`.
It's working fine on normal component but not working on component `mat-menu` with list item lazy.
I have deploy minirepo to [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f4ms3d)
Please review & help to me.
Thanks advanced

Comment: @Elias Soares: have deploy minirepo and comment my issue on code

Comment: Please add the relative code to your question. If that StackBlitz link becomes a dead link then this question has no context.

Comment: @Zze: i have commit to github. It never death. Thanks for your remask!

Comment: it will be if StackBlitz no longer exists...

Comment: This problem makes no sense when no one solved it!

Answer (score 0):

I try with click event handler and it work

```
<mat-menu #itemActions="matMenu">
  <ng-template matMenuContent let-item="item">
    <button mat-menu-item>{{item.name}}</button>
    <button mat-menu-item 
    alert-confirm 
    name="banking" 
    (click)="onDelete(item)">
      Delete
    </button>
  </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: Yep! Event onClick will working normal. But i want to use custom directive to comfirm before call api

Comment: if the lib provide custom event you can use it otherwise you cant

Comment: thanks for your contributed.
I have many collections each of which is a component and the confirm to delete item was repeated many times in each component. So I build a separate a module work for confirm.